# Is it possible to define calculated state variable in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In languages like C# it's possible to have a property which is based on other properties. Let us suppose we have `Name` and `Surname` properties. We can then define `DisplayName` property

```
get { return $"{this.Name} {this.Surname}"; }
```

I'm wondering if this is somehow possible in React, with state properties. It's legal to define a function as a value of state variable:

```
state = {
  isSomethingTrue: function() {
    return true;
  },
};
```

However then we need to execute this function to get the value. Is there any way to do it in this way that calling `this.state.isSomethingTrue` will just return the calculated value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: @ChrisG That's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You could implement that functionality like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: "Hello"
    };
  }
  get isSomethingTrue() {
    return this.state.message + " World";
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.isSomethingTrue}</div>;
  }
}
```

This is the demo:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: "Hello"
    };
  }
  get isSomethingTrue() {
    return this.state.message + " World";
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.isSomethingTrue}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is better done as a free function or a private method in the class that uses the state.

```
const isSomethingTrue(state) => state.thing === 42;
```

or

```
class Comp ... {

    isSomethingTrue = () => this.state.thing === 42;

}
```

Comment: Q specifically mentions this way as known, asking for an alternative that doesn't require a function call.